# Php mysql update query is not working?

Tags: php

I have a simple update query, but it is not working:

```
update user set active = 'Y' , delete = 'N' where id = 1;// not working
```

but if I add a special character which phpmyadmin uses then it is working

```
update `user` set `active` = 'Y' , `delete` = 'N' where `id` = 1;//its working but its database generated
```

and there is no difference except the **`** special character which is not mandatory.

Comment: `delete` is a [MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).... you cannot use it as a table or column name unless you reference it in backticks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete` is MySQL reserved keywords.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

By adding backtick, you are telling MySQL that the word enclosed is not a MySQL keyword but, rather a `database name`, `table name` or `field name`.

Thus, any conflict is avoided.

Comment: `USER` is not a reserved word, it's a keyword. Two different animals here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html - However, `USE` is. There's an `(R)` next to it, but not for `USER`.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, corrected answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE` is a reserved keyword in SQL. Without escaping it with the backtick character you will get a syntax error and the query will not work.